# How do turn text that's the result of a search into a clickable URL in Django?

Tags: python, django, url, search, full-text-search

I'm trying to make a search bar in Django that searches for pages by displaying the name and url of the page.

Right now, I can only display the url of a page as plain text when it gets searched.

I want the url to be a clickable link that leads to the page.

**This is what my code looks like currently:
**
The search results page search_page.html:

```
{% extends 'contents/main.html' %}
{% block content %}
  <center>
  {% if searched %}
    <h1>You searched for {{searched}}</h1>
    <br/>
    {% for page in pages %}
      {{ page }} - {{page.web}}<br/> <!-- page displays name of page and page.web displays url as text -->
    {% endfor %}
    
  {% else %}
    <h1>You forgot to search for a page</h1>
  {% endif %}
  </center>
{% endblock content %}
```

The method for search_page.html in views.py:

```
def search_page(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    searched = request.POST['searched']
    pages = Pages.objects.filter(name__contains=searched)
    return render(request, 'contents/search_page.html', {'searched':searched, 'pages':pages })
```

The models.py class for pages:

```
class Pages(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField('Page Name', max_length=120)
  web = models.URLField('Page URL') <!-- this gets the url of the page -->

  def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

**WHAT I'VE TRIED
**

I've tried turning page.web into a url but it gave me a TemplateSyntaxError:
`<br/> {% for page in pages %} {{ page }} - {{% url 'page.web'%}}<br/>`

Comment: try something like this `<a href="{% url 'web' %}">{{ page }}</a>`

Comment: Use django's `urlize` filter. {{page|urlize}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `page.web` variable contain **url that generated from route name specified in urls.py file** then in html you need to specify like the following to make the page as hyperlink

```
{% for page in pages %}
  <a href="{% url page.web %}"> {{ page }} </a><br/>
{% endfor %}
```

If you have an `absolute url` in the `page.web` then you may rewrite the hyperlink as follows.

```
<a href="{{ page.web }}"> {{ page }} </a><br/>
```

Comment: Whats an absolute url?

Comment: The full URL, including protocol ( http / https ), with or with out optional subdomain (e.g. www ), domain  and path (which includes the directory and slug)

Answer (score 0):

ok few suggestions and changes, first your search form

```
{% csrf_token %}
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 search-form" action="{% url 'search_results' %}" method="get">
  
  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" name = "q" aria-label="Search" id="search-input">

  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
  
</form>
```

**Note: the action = url maybe different name for yours**

**then 2nd is your views, (you need to use the get method and not POST)**

```
def SearchResultsView(request):

    query = request.GET.get('q') # (You get the "q" variable from the "name" in the html above)

    if query:
        search_results = Pages.objects.filter(
            (name__icontains=query) 

    context = {
        "search_results": search_results,
    }

    return render(request, 'blog/search_results.html', context)
```

**and finally in your search results page, just use the href tag**

```
{% for results in search_results %}

<a href="{{ results.web }}"></a><br/>

{% end for %}
```